# Prevent Backbone collection reset

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am new to Backbone. I see this in every backbone app:

```
var List = Backbone.collection.extend({
    model: model
});

var myList = new List();
```

I am a bit confused about this. This script is included in a page, and when the page is reloaded or opened again and again, it will keep instantiate new collection doesn't it?

Whenever I save some models into this collection, things are still fine. But when I start to reload the page or open the page again, it will instantiate new collection with the same name again and the collection becomes empty again.

Any suggestions to prevent this? I want collection keep the models even if reloaded.

Comment: JavaScript objects won't persist on page reload unless you have some mechanism explicitly in place to restore it, which could include data sent to the page from the server or data retrieved from a cookie or local storage.

Comment: I use ajax to POST model json to a php file. I can also use the GET method to retrieve the data that have been saved. But when the page reloaded it is gone. Or it is indeed what ajax supposed to work?

Comment: Your PHP file should save the relevant data on the server, such as in a database, then it should send the updated data to the page on load. Your page should be set up on the client side to render the data sent from the server. It sounds to me like you're not persisting your data on the server.

Comment: It is the point, can you mention some reference or tutorial to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Use myList.fetch() in your view to load data from your api resource.

Some more info at [BB site](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-fetch)

Edit:

You can save model by using [Collection create](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-create)
So first instantiate new collection, then use

```
Collection.create({
   name: 'John'
});
```

You can observe your network log to see what was posted to the api.

For your example:

```
var List = Backbone.collection.extend({
    model: model
});

var myList = new List();
myList.create({
   name: 'John'
});
```

Comment: I know it, just how to save the model data to server?